# Android Emulator Shutting down in few seconds after launching

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Well I created a new AVD from AVD manager that is "Nexus 5x API 25". When I Launch the AVD in emulators it gets launched and stay for while (30 Seconds) and Shutdown Automatically.

I tried editing the Ram Size in Config.ini of AVD, but still the same problem.

My computer Configurations are:
Intel Core i3
Ram Size: 4 GB 
HDD: 500 GB

Comment: Have you checked Logcat in Android Studio while AVD is starting?

Comment: Yes I did and its only showing Level : E , PID & TID : -1, Text: Device Disconnected

Comment: In the AVD Manager, reduce your AVD RAM size to at least 512 MB. What happens when you do this?

Comment: Still the same Problem.

Comment: I'm posting to improve the search addressing This is a possible fix of this issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44592381/5253418](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44592381/5253418)

Answer (score 4):

Solution.1 
By setting the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware. Once you did that the emulator device started up great and everything worked.
Or
Go to Menu->Tools->Android and uncheck the option Enable ADB Integration Run the application. Now the emulator will be launched, but app will not run. Once the emulator is fully launched, check the Enable ADB Integration option and re-run the app. Now the app will be launched in the already running emulator.

Comment: Thanks Pramod, but now I had this new 8GB RAM laptop and AVD is working fine now..

Answer (score 1):

My Android emulator was shutting down almost as soon as Android Studio started it.

I went to the Android Virtual Device Manager and under "Actions" for the misbehaving virtual device, I selected "Cold Boot Now".  This seemed to resolve my problem.

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat with a late 2019 version of Android Studio (v3.5.2), and I've been using it a couple of years, so it seems like a new problem to me.  I am able to resolve it by either 'wipe data' (undesirable, often) or 'cold boot' (from tools->avd manager) and then running the app.  However, this is not a permanent solution, because it always comes back.  I usually wind up doing the cold boot thing once, then be careful not to close the emulator while I am debugging so it is good until next session.

I will note i noticed Android Studio was HIGH on memory usage (which is more difficult to notice in SSD times, because you don't "hear" the hard drive thrashing from swapping memory.)  Android studio itself noticed the abnormally high memory usage and reported this to Google (presumably).  I wonder if low physical memory is/was the issue.

Update:  I just had a BIOS update for my notebook, and afterwards, I do not seem to have the same problem.  It is not clear if there was a BIOS problem (virtualization, which emulator uses, is a BIOS option) or if it was just the reboot which temporarily cleared up memory (my original guess).