# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 Emulators Stuck in Reboot

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

So yesterday I was using my TV, Mobile and Wear emulators (on Android Studio) just fine. Today in the morning an update came and I went and downloaded it. That's all I did. Since then my TV and Mobile emulator are stuck in rebooting, and I can't get them to do anything beyond that.

My AVD are both on API 23.

This is my error log:

```
Emulator: coreaudio: Could not lock voice for audioInputDeviceIOProc

Emulator: Reason: Invalid argument
```

I can't find anything related to these error messages and the emulator rebooting non stop. I tried to use Genymotion but it doesn't support TV & Wear (and I need them).

Found this on SO but it's not too related to my problem: [Simulator stuck on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071224/android-studio-3-0-canary-1-simulator-stuck-on-boot)

What I've tried so far (with no success):

- Deleting Android Studio, downloading it and reinstalling it.
- Invalidating cache & restarting.
- Deleting AVD devices and recreating them.
- Checking if Instant Run is unchecked (it was).

Anyone else had this problem and solved it? Thanks.

Comment: It works for me, you can see here..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48417715/3759584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally managed to fix this. I still have no idea of how this particular issue came to be on my machine, but this is what solved it for me:

1. On Android Studio open AVD Manager
2. On the Actions column, click on the arrow and choose "Show on Disk"
3. You will see a folder with your ADVs, and if you navigate up, you'll find a folder named "build-cache"
4. Delete everything inside "build-cache" folder
5. Delete your AVDs folders (the ones inside "avd" folder)
6. Back on the AVD Manager, delete your AVDs
7. Redownload and recreate them

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue. Its been driving me crazy for two days. What fixed it for me was adding a few extra params to run the emulator, specifically setting emulator accelerator to auto, engin to qem2 and upping the memory. emulator -avd testnexus -memory 2048 -netdelay none -accel auto -engine qemu2