# Android Studio 3.0 Emulator: Could not lock voice for audioInputDeviceIOProc

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.0

I seem to get this error while building my app on my emulator. I do not know what it the cause of it and it seems affecting my app which causes it my app to crash on the emulator.

> Emulator: coreaudio: Could not lock voice for audioInputDeviceIOProc
>   Emulator: Reason: Invalid argument

Answer (score 21):

Audio input in the Android emulator is not super reliable right now. Until it's fixed you can disable it with these steps:

1. Launch “AVD Manager”

[image]

2. On the crashing image, click the downward facing icon in the actions column and select “Show on Disk”

[image]

3. In the folder that was opened should be a `config.ini` file, open it in your favorite text editor

[image]

4. Change (or add) `hw.audioInput=yes` to `hw.audioInput=no`

[image]

5. Save and close `config.ini` and relaunch that Android emulator image—it should now work without audio input errors

Sidenote: I had issues that are possibly related and also chose to add `hw.audioOutput=no` directly after `hw.audioInput=no`. You may want to try that if `hw.audioInput=no` doesn't solve it for you.

Comment: Sorry, the error is still showing even after adding hw.audioInput=no

Comment: @JAdonaiDagdag did you try disabling audioOutput as well?

Comment: Yes. I added hw.audioInput=no in the config.ini as you mentioned

Comment: No, no. I meant did you also disable the output?

Comment: Please elaborate on how to disable the output

Comment: `hw.audioOutput=no` (at the bottom of my answer)

Comment: Yes. Already did. Sorry for the typo in the 3rd comment. It should be  
hw.audioOutput=no

Comment: what about if I don't have any files after click "Show on Disk"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch “AVD Manager”
2. Click the "Edit this AVD" of the virtual device you want to use in Android Virtual Device Manager.
   [image]
3. Click the "Show Advanced Settings" in (AVD's) Virtual Device Configuration.
   [image]
4. Go to "Emulated Performance" section in (AVD's) Virtual Device Configuration and select "Cold boot" of "Boot option:" and click "Finish".
   [image]
5. Relaunch your virtual device and rerun your app on the emulator(Virtual Device).