# Emulator: WARNING: HAXM 6.0.5 is installed. Please install HAXM >= 6.2.1 to fix compatibility issues on Mac

Tags: android, ios, android-emulator, ibm-mobilefirst, haxm

Emulator is not running. I had already installed HAXM 6.2.1. Please checkout the image.

[image]

So, I just reinstalled the HAXM. Anow now another problem occurs. Please checkout image second and third.

*6:54 PM    Emulator: Reason: Invalid argument*

*6:54 PM    Emulator: coreaudio: Could not lock voice for audioInputDeviceIOProc*

[image]
[image]

Comment: It works for me, you can see here..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48417715/3759584

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Navigate to **[Android SDK Folder]** --> **Extra** --> **Intel** --> **Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager**
and double click on HAXM installer **intelhaxm-android.exe** (on Mac **IntelHAXM_6.2.1.dmg**) and install it manually.

If you do not have latest version of **HAXM** then you can open sdk manager in android studio and download it.

[image]

Although, this should be installed automatically when you install Android Studio. See below.

[image]

> **Answering @DougThompson Question:** 
>   What if HAXM installer not installing automatically ?

[image]

In that case,

1. you can download HAXM installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm.
2. Keep the installer at **[Android SDK Folder] --> Extra --> Intel**
3. Extract and install it manually.

now you are done.

Comment: Thank you!!! this is how I solved too. Maybe android studio did not launch the dmg? Anyway big thumbs up!

Comment: @MacKentoch It should launch automatically when you install android studio. but unfortunately sometime it doesn't happen.

Comment: Totally awesome!  Thanks (Thumbs up brother)

Comment: Sorry @GaurabKumar, my Operating System is a mac OS Sierra, so I voted in the answer bellow, which our colleague #gMale, that was more specific in my case, only that I clicked on your post when commenting.
but thanks also

Comment: Certificate expired a few days ago. But can install newer version. See https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/219#issuecomment-509053176

Answer (score 16):

### On a Mac

- navigate to `[ANDROID_HOME]/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`
- open and install `IntelHAXM_6.2.1.dmg`

The easiest way to do that from the CLI is to type `open IntelHAXM_6.2.1.dmg` then double click the `IntelHAXM_6.2.1.mpkg` file and follow the installation prompts.

*Note: I tried running the `silent_install.sh` file in that folder and it failed so I'm guessing that's the root problem here–that script may have a bug with how it mounts the DMG.*

Comment: Just tried silent_install.sh using sudo, installation passed.

Answer (score 6):

With Android Studio, you can find `HAXM Installer` under `SDK tools` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you cannot uninstall it from the Control Panel?
What happens when you cant locate the old version to download, to put into a folder for the MSI to uninstall?
This is where your fancy 'clean up my PC' programs removed all the old installer temp files. So do you have to have a  external hard drive for all your old installs? It would have been so nice if they used NPM and the uninstaller could always find the repository to remove the old version before updating to the new one.
[image]